# How to Enforce Password Complexity Policy settings Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

Is there any way we can enforce the password policy changes with the immediate effect i.e enforce the user to change the password while logon if it is not met newly added policy settings.

I heard that something we can do with Powershell WMI Bridge Scripting. I am very much new to it any help on this topic please.

But as per  Miscrosoft

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/hh994562(v=ws.10)
```

the new password policy will come to effect when user changes password manually or age of the policy is over. not immediate.

is there any way we can enforce password change?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PowerShell` to check the `User must change password at next logon` check box for every user.

```
Set-ADUser -Filter * -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$true
```

would do just that. But please don't run it without knowing what you're doing!

Comment: Not in the AD, I have to  to do the changes in the system level config only.  like in password policy settings.

Comment: To do the above for local users, you have to use: `Set-LocalUser -Name "MyLocalUser" -UserMayChangePassword:$true`. If your question is about how to configure it in the system config (local policies), then this is the wrong forum. You should ask on https://superuser.com/ instead.